# html legend tag explore not working center

Tags: html, css

here explore .. not work

[image]

.

bottom is crome... correct

[image]

bottom is crome...

```
legend.scheduler-border {
width:inherit;
font-size: 1.8em !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
text-align: center !important;
}

fieldset.scheduler-border {
border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
padding: 32px 0 70px 2px;
margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
        box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}
```

here code is line front legend tag

Comment: Html code please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple Example of legend tag that align in center

```html
   

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend align="center">Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text" size="30"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" size="30"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: No problem , Keep coding :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
legend {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @Gowtham's answer works fine, but it's considered best practice to do this sort of styling in the css if possible rather than "inline" in the markup. If `legend {text-align: center}` doesn't work, it's because the style is losing out to some other style you applied somewhere else. Your `!important`s make me think that's what's going on -- if you need to use `!important` it's because you've given conflicting styles to `legend` somewhere else